# Access Hidden field value from POP dialog from parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I Have a Page Say Page1.Chtml , In this page I have  two DIV element like below

```
  <div id="1">
     Some test
    <div id="2"> </div>
  </div>
```

Content in Div 2 is dynamically put run time and displayed DIV 1 as pop up.

Now in DIV 2 I have some hidden file now i would like to access this hidden field in page "Page1.Chtml" in javascript.And hidden field is

```
<input type="hidden" id="DlrhdnPageNumberVal" name="DlrhdnPageNumberVal" />
```

I accessing like below , but it is not working coming undefned.

```
var PrevsValue= $('DlrhdnPageNumber').val();
```

Please help if it is possible.

Thanks !!!

Comment: You can access those fields using by name or by id jquery selectors.

Comment: Please post your hidden fields and jquery code that you have so far.

Comment: give an id to the element and access it using id

Comment: Code added to access but not working @bhushan

Comment: is `DlrhdnPageNumber` an id or name of the hidden fields?

Comment: var PrevsValue= $('#DlrhdnPageNumber').val();  you have to use '#' if your are using id for selector

Comment: The Hidden field is as : <input type="hidden" id="DlrhdnPageNumber" name="DlrhdnPageNumber"  />

Comment: Use `var PrevsValue= $('#DlrhdnPageNumber').val();` to read the hidden value but make sure that this id must be unique through out the DOM

Comment: Yes Bhusan I am using same way but it is not working @bhusan

Comment: Have you checked for any console errors on browser? and make sure that there must be only one element with id as `DlrhdnPageNumber`. Post your hidden element html code. Also, if possible provide jsfiddle link with your problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access an HTML element using jQuery you need to keep in mind a few selector rules, such as if you want to access an element by id you need to prefix it with a '#' character and if you want to access an element by css class you need to prefix it with `.`:

`var hiddenValue = $("#hidden").val();//access by id`

`var hiddenValue = $(".hidden").val();//access by css class`

Below is a simple example using `ViewBag` and a bootstrap modal popup.I set `ViewBag.Value` in the controller action and store it in the view inside a hidden field

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Value = "Sample Value";
    return View();
}
```

**View:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnLaunch").click(function () {
            $(".modal-body").empty();
            var hiddenValue = $("#hidden").val();
            alert(hiddenValue);
            $(".modal-body").html(hiddenValue);
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });

    });
</script>

<button type="button" id="btnLaunch">Launch modal</button>
<div id="div2">
    <input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.Value" id="hidden" />
</div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but my hidden field is in Model-body and the i would like to access in java scrip 

but in your case hidden field is out of model pop up.

Comment: It doesn't matter where it is as long as it has id="hidden"  you will be able to access it from javascript.Give it a try.Also id doesn't have to be called `hidden` you can give it your own unique name

Comment: No luck used same way :( .OK can you tell how to access hidden field which you have metioned from Model-body pop up

Comment: Just copy and paste the code I have as is and understand how it works

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Use `var PrevsValue= $('#DlrhdnPageNumber').val();` to read the hidden value but make sure that this id must be unique through out the DOM.

You can use name attribute selector also to read the value, but provided that there must be only one element with same name, otherwise you have to handle it differently.

For one name element - `var PrevsValue= $('input[name="DlrhdnPageNumber"]:first').val();`

For multiple name elements 
var PrevsValues= $('input[name="DlrhdnPageNumber"]');

```
for (var i=0; i<PrevsValues.length; i++)
{
  var value = PrevsValues[i].val();
}
```